# Unable to import URL class from node 'url' module in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, webpack-5

I'm using next.js with webpack 5 and all of a sudden my URL class import isn't working anymore.

Running `npm run build` gives the following error:

> Attempted import error: 'URL' is not exported from 'url' (imported as 'URL').

The code in question is:

```js
import { URL } from "url";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Error404 = () => {
  // Server side url class is undefined on client so choose based on which is available
  const Url = globalThis?.URL || URL;

  const defaultImageUrl = new Url(defaultImage, PUBLIC_URL).href;
...
```

I'm trying to use the [WHATWG URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api) because it's supposed to be a `"Browser-compatible URL class"`

This issue started in webpack 5 and was not present while using webpack 4.
How do I fix my import such that webpack 5 doesn't give me the import error anymore?

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to fix this issue? I'm currently struggling with these 3 errors. Similar case scenario like yours, webpack 5.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72651313/wrong-url-imports-for-sentry-library-in-a-react-rewired-app

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` constructor is accessible as a property on the global object, have you tried to use it without import?

Also, since your `Error404` component is probably universal (should be available both server and client side), then you can't just use server-side modules, they might not compile for browser. Luckily, `URL` is not one of them, it can be used on both sides and even without import.